# how to bind efficiently a label widget using perl Tkx

Tags: callback

clicking on a label (or a list box), both using "bind" is not efficient

i tried ti bind a label to a callback subroutine
a button widget works fine (no bind but -command)
fenetre widget is an unusefull test (same problem without it)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tkx;

sub gd
{
print "gd\n";
}

# Créer une fenêtre Tkx
my $mw = Tkx::widget->new('.');
$mw->g_wm_title("Musique");
$mw->g_wm_resizable(1,1);
$mw->g_wm_focus();

my $fenetre=$mw->new_ttk__frame();
$fenetre-> g_pack(-side=>'left', -expand=>1, -fill=>'both');

my $label = $fenetre->new_ttk__label(-text => "Cliquez ici");
$label->g_pack;

# Lier les événements souris au label
$label->g_bind("<<MouseDown>>", \&gd);


# Bouton pour quitter le programme
my $bouton_quitter = $fenetre->new_ttk__button(
        -text => "Quitter",
        -command => sub { exit }
    )->g_pack(-side => 'right');

Tkx::MainLoop();
```